# Does Superman have fireproof eyelashes?

Tags: dc, superman

Superman's heat vision obviously has a lot of 'heat', so how does it not burn his eyelashes?

Do his eyelids have a high burning temperature or does he apply too much Lakme?

For clarification, I am simply asking - Why does the Heat from his 'Heat vision' not burn off his eyelashes??

@Eike Pierstorff's comment further elaborates my point that if Superman's beard is unable to handle the heat, how do the eyelashes handle it?

Comment: *That's* what's wrong with his heat vision?!

Comment: Strange question. Considering that he's clearly superhumanly durable in general -- sufficiently so that he can walk through Earthly flames without sustaining any apparent damage or feeling any apparent pain -- wouldn't it naturally follow that the same applies to his eyelashes? Are you entertaining the possibility that his eyelashes are no more durable than those of a normal human?

Comment: @LogicDictates apparently he shaves with his heat vision, so amazingly asking why his eyelashes are heat resistant when his beard isn't is not that silly a question (within the confines of this site at least).

Comment: In Superman #396, Superman was knocked down by his own heat vision reflected back on him. Soon after in Action Comics 558 his heat vision gets turned on permanently, he handles it by fighting crime with his eyes closed (ouch) Since his eyelid can take that they must be more protected from heat vision than the rest of him.

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff - I think you misunderstood my point. My point is that Superman's body in general, including his hair, is clearly heatproof to some degree, since he can endure Earthly flames without being visibly harmed. Note that I said **Earthly** flames. He is not truly invulnerable, so sufficiently extreme temperatures will burn any part of his body. Perhaps the question would benefit from some clarification: is it asking whether Superman's eyelashes are heatproof at all, or is it asking whether they cannot be burned by any degree of heat?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/is-superman-immune-to-his-own-special-abilities/245332

Comment: Welcome to what TVTropes calls [Required Secondary Powers](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RequiredSecondaryPowers). (If you haven't read TVTropes before, prepare to lose an afternoon exploring it...)

Comment: This question also reminds me of this one nightmare Superman has in Justice League, where he loses control of his power and his heat vision even burns through his eyelid: https://youtu.be/DTj4yk5U9ig?t=15

Comment: The reason I'm seeking clarification here is because I might be able to provide a decent answer -- I can certainly think of evidence that is at least partially relevant to this question in my mind -- but I don't like attempting to answer questions without being clear on what precisely is being asked. So for the time being, I won't attempt to answer this, but I would be inclined to do if this question is clarified.

Comment: I'm more curious about his eyes. They should be melting and leaking.

Comment: I suspect mainly because people without eyelashes look reeeeaaally strange and off-putting they got plot (or rather: aesthetics!) armor.

Comment: @DavidW Diffraction grating.

Comment: The beams appear to come out of his *pupils*. That would obviate the need for his eyelashes to be fireproof. We certainly know that he can shave his own hair using his eye beams, so that would also suggest that they can be cut or burned if he fires his eye-beams at them at the right frequency