# What happens if Harry wants to tame his hair?

Tags: harry-potter

In [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94517/how-did-harry-get-his-hair-cut-at-hogwarts?rq=1), it's explained that Harry's hair magically remains in a similar state. It can regrow at an extraordinary pace... but what happens if Harry wants, say, a mowhawk? Or grow his hair long for a Triwizard tournament-?

[image: Hair in Goblet of Fire]

This is reflected in the action figure of Harry... (showing this isn't a mistake in the film).

[image: Harry fig gobby fire]

Now, granted, this detail isn't mentioned in the books, but what is mentioned is: 
Neither Mrs Weasley or Aunt Petunia can alter Harry's hair-
it regrows when Petunia tries to cut it:

> Aunt Petunia [...] cut his hair [...]. Next morning, however, he had gotten up to find his hair exactly as it had been before Aunt Petunia had sheared it off.
>       Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, chapter 2, "The Boy Who Lived"

And even before Harry's important hearing, it remains stubbornly untameable...

> Mrs. Weasley was attacking his hair with a wet comb. She pressed hard on the top of his head. “Doesn’t it ever lie flat?” she said desperately. Harry shook his head.
>       Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, chapter 7, "The Ministry of Magic"

And Harry apparently can't brush it either:

> “He raised his hand automatically and tried to make his hair lie flat. “You’re fighting a losing battle there, dear,” said his mirror in a wheezy voice.”
>   ― J.K. Rowling, Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban

So, what does mista Potta ever do when he wants his hair to look nice?

Comment: The answer to the other question you link to at the top says "Harry's hair didn't grow extraordinarily fast; it only regrew magically fast in response to the unwanted haircuts he received from aunt Petunia." Can't say for sure if that's accurate, but if so it suggests his hair doesn't automatically regrow to the same length, it just "rebels" against *unwanted* haircuts by regrowing to the length he prefers.

Comment: This is not a useful question in the least, and is very silly. I suppose if Harry cared about the condition of his hair on a regular basis, he could use "Sleek-Eazy" hair potion. It worked for Hermione.

Comment: @Slytherincess - Ah, but it's actually quite interesting that Harry's relative *invented* "Sleekeazy's Hair Potion".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would seem that all it took was time, and presumably a metric tonne of hair-product like [Wizard's Sculpting Gel](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wizard%27s_Sculpting_Gel) or something similar.

[image]

Interestingly, Harry's ancestor [Fleamont Potter](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fleamont_Potter) invented a haircare product called [Sleekeazy's Hair Potion](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sleekeazy%27s_Hair_Potion), guaranteed to....

> ... *tame even the most bothersome barnet*.
>
> <sub><sup>[Pottermore: The Potter Family](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-potter-family)</sup></sub>

That being the case, it's reasonably to assume that his ancestor had the same difficulties with his hair as Harry, and that this was the inspiration for his (evidently much successful) haircare product.

Comment: you've turned my useless question into a good answer, well done :D