# Why couldn't Henry Cavill simply shave his mustache for his Superman role and use a fake mustache for his other role?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, justice-league-2017

It's famous that Cavill did all his shoot for *Justice League* (2017) in his mustache because he had another shooting going on for *Mission Impossible 6* (2018) which required his mustache.

[image]

And then, Warner Bros. removed his mustache with CGI which terribly failed at several places.

[image]

Why didn't they go for simple option: Henry Cavill could simply shave his mustache for his Superman role and use a fake mustache at Mission Impossible 6 set?

Comment: Because the other film wanted an authentic moustache?

Comment: Because he was under contract elsewhere and they point-blank refused to let him

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82949/why-did-warner-bros-spend-25-million-to-cgi-out-henry-cavills-mustache

Comment: @Chris Yeah, they could also have shown that Superman's corpse got mustache in his grave.

Comment: A fake mustache would have looked stupid!

Comment: @starpilotsix No way. Make up artists are way more advanced than CGI artists in terms of quality.

Comment: I'm not saying it wouldn't have looked better than the CGI-removal, I'm saying they probably cared more about their product than the Justice League. ;)

Comment: https://twitter.com/netw3rk/status/932670061000646656

Comment: The real mustache looks fake

Comment: The real question here is how did the other cast members of Justice League keep a straight face in any of the reshoots with Cavill?

Comment: *"It's famous that Cavill did all his shoot for Justice League...in his mustache"* [No, just the reshoots](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/82953/22662).

Comment: The should have put makeup on over the mustache - [that always works great](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Joker_(Batman_1966_TV_Series))!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to user [LDN_Films on Reddit](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:huYfUvE_Lb8J:https://i.reddit.com/r/DC_Cinematic/comments/7f9rea/other_im_a_vfx_artist_on_these_films_ama/%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) (posting anonymously, but "checked out" and vouched for as genuine by Reddit's own AMA team), the issue was that Cavill was already in pre-production for his next film and required permission from the studio to change his appearance. Paramount point-blank refused to allow him to do so.

This would strongly imply that Cavill was *under contract to grow a moustache* for the role and *under financial penalty if he broke his contract*.

> **Q:** *What was your team's reaction when you heard you had to CGI the moustache?*
>
> **LDN_Films:** *A mix - to some people it's a cool little project to get stuck in to and another problem to solve, which is what a lot of VFX is about. Challenging. To me, as a fan, **I was annoyed haha Paramount should've shaved him and stuck a fake one on for MI6. Ridiculously petty of them. We did tests on already shot footage of Superman to add a beard as well to show the MI6 team at Paramount it was loads easier, and Warner Bros offered to pay for all the beard adding shots in MI6. They said no.***

The director for MI:6 claimed (in a [now-deleted tweet](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1685079/why-henry-cavill-isnt-wearing-a-fake-mustache-in-mission-impossible-6-according-to-the-director)) that it was because of all the *high-octane action* that a fake moustache simply wouldn't work.

> *In exactly one year you’ll understand: The only way to keep a fake
> ‘stache on Henry Cavill would be a liberal dose of staples.* **#MI6
> 07.27.18**
>
> — ChristopherMcQuarrie (@chrismcquarrie) [July 25, 2017](https://twitter.com/chrismcquarrie/status/889893826055241729)

So we're left with two options, depending on who you believe;

- **An allegation of sheer pettiness**
  or
- **that there were genuine concerns that a fake 'tash would simply fly away in the middle of a multi-million dollar stunt sequence.**

It's also possible that neither are true and that he'd simply already filmed some [VFX pre-visualisation shots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Previsualization) or that Paramount wanted the option of incorporating early test footage into the finished film. Having him shave and then use a fake moustache would make these difficult due to continuity issues.

---

Comment: And let's be honest here. If Paramount can cost DC Films $30M simply by refusing to allow their star to shave, then that's a big win for them.

Comment: I believe, your comment is the real answer.. :)

Comment: @Bat True, but they would never admit it so it can not be sourced!

Comment: @Valorum To be clear, it was $25-$30 million for the entire reshoot process, not that much simply for removing the mustache ([Movies.SE goes into more detail](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/82949/12783)).

Comment: @Thunderforge - Sure. And those numbers themselves are highly suspect because of Hollywood accounting practices.

Comment: More particularly https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/82952/5652 has more detail on why he had to keep the stache - the MI6 director said "In exactly one year you’ll understand: The only way to keep a fake ‘stache on Henry Cavill would be a liberal dose of staples." which suggests (to me) its going to get pulled around or something in such a way that a fake one would come off and it needs to be real (or maybe something else but that was my first thought). May be worth checking the reference on that answer and adding a similar reference to this answer (it doesn't feel worth adding a new one).

Comment: @Chris - Worth adding in. Cheers.

Comment: `a fake 'tash would simply fly away in the middle of a multi-million dollar stunt sequence` ~> Even if they couldn't find a good glue, he could grow that much mustache within no time. I get double dense mustache than that within a month.

Comment: @Bat Mustaches don't grow with the same speed on every man. Who knows, perhaps he has one of the slowest staches known to mankind. But this is straying into [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com) territory.

Comment: @Bat On me, that's about four months of 'stache growing.

Comment: @Mast Still, he could take extra dose of Testosterone to make it grow faster.

Comment: I don't think it's petty in the slightest, to be honest. The producers probably made it very clear that he must grow and keep a real moustache, and the actor agreed. It would be very unprofessional of him to even ask if he could shave it after agreeing to the terms. At this point, the reason is irrelevant, so it can't be petty.

Comment: Two additional points to include - learned mannerisms of having vs not having a mo.  It would be extra work for the actor to remember to act like he has a Kaiser.  Call them tweaks or twitches, but most moustashioed men will wipe their lip curtain with their hand or a napkin or whatever, immediately after eating/drinking.  Those without a Fu Manchu wouldn't do the same as frequently.   Plus a really decent Wedge-of-Wool takes 6~12 months to "fill in" properly.  Anything less could look like a teenager's pencil-stashe and that thin look would be aggravated by the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Henry was contract obligated to not shave.
Yeah! Incredible as it may seem, that's the truth.

But instead of Justice League waIting, which would have clearly have benefited the movie.
They simply decided to CGI the scenes with Superman.

That's why almost every time we got a close up on Superman face, he seemed weird.

Comment: Do you have anything to support this? A link or quote would help this answer a lot

Comment: How does Soop shave anyways?